# Why won't drop down reset?

Tags: jquery, select

I MUST be doing something stupid, but I have a deadline and staring at this is NOT finding it.

Please see the VERY simple JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxbVX/4/

```
<span>Select 'One', 'Two' or 'Three' from the drop down.<br /></span>
<span>Then click the 'Reset' button'.<br /></span>
<span>Why does the Drop Down not reset to 'Please Select'?<br /></span>

<input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" name="reset" /><br />

<script>
    var $reset = $('#reset');

    $reset .click(function() {
        $('#myddl').val("0");     
    });

</script>

<select id="myddl" name="myddl">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The problem is that you're trying to get the `select` before it actually exists on the page. Notice that your js code is placed before `reset` definition.
Place your code inside [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to be sure that all elements already loaded.</strike>

I'm afraid I was wrong, the only problem on your jsfiddler is that you're not referencing jquery library. Take a look to the left panel. At the top you find a dropdown saying `No-Library (pure Js)`. Change that for any jquery version and your code will work.

Comment: While you are absolutely correct for the JSFiddle, it seems the non-dumbed-down example in my code has something else wrong - because that ain't it. Well - maybe I better prove that out. :) Thanks. Will update later.

Comment: So much for simplifying a problem until the solution is obvious - I still have the bug. The JS include is the last line before the /body tag, so the doc should already be loaded. However, I added the $(function()...) anyways just for kicks. No difference. Weird.

Comment: @Eric: do you have any error on browser console? I wonder if you can recreate the issue on jsfiddler